# Find which cells have a dropdown filter applied - Interop Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop

I'm trying to check whether a worksheet has any filters (whether applied or not), if so, I'd like to figure out which cells or row have a filter function.

I've tried:
`var filter = ((dynamic) range.AutoFilter(rowStart, j);`

and this one to see if there are any in the whole worksheet

```
var range = workbookWorksheet.UsedRange; 
var sheet= application.ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet;
Range filteredRange = range.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, XlSpecialCellsValue.xlTextValues);
var sdsds = filteredRange.AutoFilter();
```

Trying to do this without Plus or another library other than Interop. Not sure if this is possible but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get the cells that have the filter dropdown?

Comment: @EylM yes, i.e. the headings, however they're no always on the first or second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the [AutoFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.autofilter) property to check if there are filters in the `Worksheet`.

In order to get the addresses, you need to iterate over the filters.
Use the [On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filter.on) property of the filter to check if it's on/off.

```
    // check if there are filters in the worksheet.
    if (workbookWorksheet.AutoFilter == null ||
        workbookWorksheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Count == 0)
    {
        // no filters
        return;
    }

    // go over the filters and get the addresses
    for (var i = 1; i < ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Count; i++)
    {
        var filter = ws.AutoFilter.Filters[i];
        Console.WriteLine(filter.On); // print/check if the filter is on.

        Range range = ws.AutoFilter.Range[1, i];
        Console.WriteLine(range.Address); // address of the filter cell
    }
```

**Update:**
Not sure it's the most efficient way, but it does the job.
This functions takes range as the parameter and check if it has a filter and returns true if the filter is on.

Note: If you prefer to work with absolute address, change the parameter to string address.

```
private bool HasFilterOn(Range range)
{       
    // check if there are filters in the worksheet.
    if (workbookWorksheet.AutoFilter == null ||
        workbookWorksheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Count == 0)
    {
        // no filters
        return false;
    }

    // go over the filters and get the addresses
    for (var i = 1; i < workbookWorksheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Count; i++)
    {
        var filter = workbookWorksheet.AutoFilter.Filters[i];

        if (workbookWorksheet.AutoFilter.Range[1, i].Address == range.Address)
            return filter.On;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would i go about passing in an address and see if a filter is there, whether or not it is in its filtered state